# Response of facebook send button

Tags: facebook-apps

how can i get the response of facebook send button whether it is a success or failure

```
  FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        status : false, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML add it here
        oauth : true
    });
 (function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";  
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`FB.Event.subscribe`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.4) will let you get that data.

Try something like

`FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(sharedURL) {
// your code here
});`

Comment: Do you have a full example of the code you're using?